# Django Rest Framework + JWT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm using djangorestframework-jwt and I can authenticate just fine, but I'm having some trouble staying authenticated. I get a `"Signature has expired."` error after ~5m or so.

Am I just using it wrong? My assumption was that I'd pass it the token for every request and that'd keep me authenticated. Logging out would just mean forgetting the token.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication) says that the default expiration delta is 5 minutes. See `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA` setting. The framework seems to assume that you want to implement token refresh.

Comment: Since you can't regularly refresh, is the expectation then that with mobile apps you'd just be required to set a really really long `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA` and an even longer `JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA`? (Let's say you're using JWT to auth an iPhone app and they dont' open the app for 3-4 weeks)

Comment: Yeah, just set the expiration time to 4 weeks or whatever is your expected time for a returning user.